# The long exact cohomology sequence on compact complex manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

The classical $exponential sequence$ on a complex manifold $X$ is the short exact sequence  $$0\longrightarrow\mathbb Z\longrightarrow\mathcal O_{X}\longrightarrow\mathcal O_{X}^{*}\longrightarrow 0.$$

Here, $\mathbb Z$ is the locally constant sheaf, $\mathcal O_{X}$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions, $\mathcal O_{X}^{*}$ is the sheaf of non-vanishing holomorphic functions.
Then,we can get a long exact  cohomology sequence $$H^{1}(X,\mathbb   Z)\longrightarrow H^{1}(X,\mathcal O_{X})\longrightarrow H^{1}(X,\mathcal  O_{X}^{*})\longrightarrow H^{2}(X,\mathbb Z).$$

My question is,when $X$ is compact ,then we can get a claim:
$$H^{1}(X,\mathbb   Z)\longrightarrow H^{1}(X,\mathcal O_{X})$$is injective.Maybe this is a very trivial problem,can anyone give me some advice?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look at the $H^0$ level of the exact sequence. Since it gives a short exact sequence (on a compact complex manifold, the only global holomorphic functions are constants), the final map is surjective, and this means that the exact sequence you wrote down in fact starts with a $0\longrightarrow$.

Comment: Dear @Ted Shifrin,thank you so much for giving the solution,but I still have some confusion.For the long eact sequence $$0\longrightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathbb   Z)\longrightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathcal O_{x})\longrightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathcal  O_{x}^{*})\longrightarrow H^{1}(X,\mathbb Z).$$ Do you mean $H^{0}(X,\mathcal  O_{x}^{*})=0$?If this statement is correct,then$H^{0}(X,\mathbb   Z)\longrightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathcal O_{x})$ is surjective?

Comment: No, $H^0(X,\mathscr O_X^*) \cong \Bbb C^*$, and the exponential map $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C^*$ is surjective.

Comment: Dear @Ted Shifrin,thanks for your patience and time!

Comment: Sure thing. Just please remember to accept the answer when you are satisfied that you understand it. :)

Comment: OK,I just have accepted it!Thanks again.